# modx revolution pdomenu different templates for each level

Tags: php, menu, modx, modx-revolution

I wonder how to define template for each level in pdoMenu params if I want to make multilevel menu on my webpage?

For example the structure for menu is something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div></div>
    <img src="assets/img/1.png" />
    <a>Link 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>Sub link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Sub link 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
    <img src="assets/img/2.png" />
    <a>Link 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>Sub link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Sub link 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see first level of menu includes div and img tags but second does not.
That is why I need to define different templates via pdoMenu.
Unfortunately, there is no comprehensive examples for pdoMenu parameters.
It seems that pdoMenu provides this feature only for "&levelClass" parameter which gives incrementation for css class for each level.

May be I should use some other approach for this purpose? Pdoresources or getresources?

Answer (score 0):

Wayfinder does have some menu template options you could explore: https://docs.modx.com/extras/evo/wayfinder#Wayfinder-TemplateParameters

But, for the time being, the only way I could think to do this would be to use getResources.

For your first level you would use a simple getResources call that restricts it to 1 level of depth, but in that .tpl you would have a 2nd getResources call.

For example:

```
[[!getResources?
  &parents=`1`
  &depth=`1`
  &tpl=`firstLevel`
]]
```

Then `firstLevel` would look something like:

```
<li>
  <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">[[+pagetitle]]</a>
  [[!getResources?
      &parents=`[[~[[+id]]]]`
      &depth=`0`
      &tplWrapper=`menuWrapper`
      &tpl=`secondLevel`
    ]]
</li>
```

`menuWrapper` would just wrap `secondLevel` and look like:

```
<ul>[[+output]]</ul>
```

`secondLevel` would just look like:

```
<li>
  <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">[[+pagetitle]]</a>
</li>
```

This is one way to go about it. The above is untested so you might want to keep that in mind.

As a side note, if you only want to add images you can use css, eg:

```
li ul li:first-child:before {
    content: url('../images/image.png');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.This problem was solved by **Bruno17** in a simpler way. [You can look here](https://forums.modx.com/thread/101884/pdomenu-different-tamplates-for-each-level#dis-post-549481).